# What's the difference between "regime" and "regimen"?

Tags: differences

What's the difference between *regime* and *regimen*?

Comment: +1. I was just wondering about "Loss of regimen" right now, because of this comic: http://theoatmeal.com/comics/working_home

Comment: ... that's what inspired me to ask this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regime usually refers to a system of government.

A regimen is a plan that one adheres to (i.e. regimented).

People misuse regime a lot of the time when they mean regimen, especially relating to diets.

Comment: *Regime* also has the meaning of a systematic plan (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regime) and *regimen* also has the meaning of system of government (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regimen).  The difference is much more difficult to piece apart than what you are portraying.

Comment: That's why I added 'usually'.

Answer (score 17):

Generally speaking, the two words have the same ultimate etymology, from Latin *regimin*, meaning “position of authority, direction, set of rules”. In many cases, either word can be used, and their meanings have substantial overlap:

> **[regime](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regime)**
>   **1 a** : *regimen*<sup>1</sup>
>   **b** : a regular pattern of occurrence or action (as of seasonal rainfall)
>   **c** : the characteristic behavior or orderly procedure of a natural phenomenon or process
>   **2 a** : mode of rule or management
>   **b** : a form of government <a socialist *regime*>
>   **c** : a government in power
>   **d** : a period of rule
>
> **[regimen](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regimen)**
>   **1 a** : a systematic plan (as of diet, therapy, or medication) especially when designed to improve and maintain the health of a patient
>   **b** : a regular course of action and especially of strenuous training <the daily *regimen* of athletes>
>   **2** : government, rule
>   **3** : *regime* <sup>1c</sup>

The definitions reference each other in several places reflecting the substantial overlap in the two words’ meanings. However, the two words are frequently used differently, so let’s look at what collocates (frequent neighbor words) using the Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA):

These words most commonly appear before *regimen* (function words like *the* excluded)

```
EXERCISE   116
TRAINING   109
TREATMENT   80
DAILY       65
WORKOUT     39
DRUG        38
FITNESS     36
STRICT      33
MEDICAL     24
```

Whereas these words commonly appear before *regime*:

```
MILITARY       449
COMMUNIST      383
IRAQI          232
AUTHORITARIAN  203
OLD            200
DEMOCRATIC     156
TALIBAN        145
CASTRO         139
NAZI           139
```

From these results we can see clearly that sense 2 of *regime*, the one having to do with government, is the most salient one for that word (at least when it is used with an attributive). However, if we look up the frequent collocates for *regimen* with *regime*, we do find some (albeit fewer) results:

```
EXERCISE   20
TRAINING    6
TREATMENT   9
DAILY       4
WORKOUT     6
DRUG        6
FITNESS     4
STRICT      8
MEDICAL     1
```

From this we can conclude that indeed the sense of *regime* meaning “a systematic plan” or “regular course of action” is also a current usage, and not one that merits criticism for being a “misuse”.

Comment: I'm glad @Robusto has just tickled this old question, which predates me joining ELU. This is an excellent clear and thorough answer, so I welcome the chance to upvote it in hopes that when future visitors see it, they'll be just a little bit more aware of there being more support for your/our position than there is for the (disappointingly, *accepted*) answer with that drivel about *People misuse regime a lot of the time when they mean regimen* (I'll go lie down now until my enraged apoplexy subsides! :)

Answer (score 2):

In US English,

- 'a regime change' is, for example, a coup/junta/putsch in a government
- 'a regimen change' is, for example, eating more yogurt.

Comment: The [OED notes](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/161267#eid26201188) that “*Regimen* rather than *regime* is now the usual word in the United States and in *Med[icine]*.; in British English *regime* is more usual.”

Answer (score 2):

'Regimen' is all but unheard of in Australian English either. We use 
'regime', whether it's exercise, diet, military or government contexts.

Answer (score -1):

The word *regimen* is all but unheard of in the UK and British English.

*Regime* is the correct term in the UK in all contexts.